# How to simplify large respond_to blocks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anyone have recommendations for how I can reduce `respond_to` blocks? It seems like my JSON formatting takes up a considerable amount of space. The controller, for the most part, responds with HTML but this specific method is called via Ajax and responds in JSON:

```
def create
  # initial setup

  respond_to do |format|
    unless paid_cash == true || PayPalPayments::OrderValidator.call(order_id)
      format.json do
        render json: {
          status: :unhandled_error,
          message: 'Invalid order ID supplied?'
        }, status: 400
      end
    end

    if @submitted_application.save(context: :create)
      MembershipMailer.with(application: @submitted_application).signup_confirmation.deliver_later

      format.json do
        render json: {
          status: :created,
          modal: render_to_string(
            partial: 'membership_confirmation_modal.html.erb'
          )
        }
      end
    else
      format.json do
        render json: {
          status: :validation_errors,
          errors: @submitted_application.errors
        }, status: 400
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In 99.9% of cases `x == true` can be reduced to `x` when inside a conditional. Could `paid_cash` be some other truthy value like `'yes'` instead?

Comment: I'd recommend trying to rewrite the logic from a compound `unless` and `if/else` to a `case` statement. `unless` complicates the logic because it's basically a `not if` followed by another `if/else` and chains of ifs are bad enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing a *lot* of JSON responses, like you're building a JSON API, then it would make sense to make a method to simplify that pattern. For example, create a method like this:

```
def respond_json(content)
  status = content[:status]

  render(
    json: content,
    status: STATUS_CODE_REMAPPED[status] || status
  )
end
```

Where that works with the structure you've established and uses it to generate the correct `render` call. As this only works with data structured a specific way, it helps enforce consistency in your responses.

This depends on mapping the internal codes to the Rails response codes:

```
STATUS_CODE_REMAPPED = {
  created: :ok,
  unhandled_error: :bad_request,
  validation_errors: :bad_request
}
```

Where using the [symbol codes](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/10/13/list-of-rails-status-code-symbols/) helps the code become more self-explanatory.

Another thing to note is your order verification could be extracted into a `before_action` handler:

```
before_action :verify_order_id, only: [ :create ]

def verify_order_id
  return if paid_cash || PayPalPayments::OrderValidator.call(order_id)

  respond_json(
    status: :unhandled_error,
    message: 'Invalid order ID supplied?'
  )
end
```

Where if that handler renders something the chain stops as the request is considered serviced.

This dramatically reduces how much code is left in the controller action:

```
def create
  @submitted_application.save!(context: :create)

  MembershipMailer.with(application: @submitted_application).signup_confirmation.deliver_later

  respond_json(
    status: :created,
    modal: render_to_string(
      partial: 'membership_confirmation_modal.html.erb'
    )
  )

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  respond_json(
    status: :validation_errors,
    errors: @submitted_application.errors
  )
end
```

I've used `save!` here so that the *expected* path is much simpler, there's no branching. If/when an error occurs *then* you can go off into the exception handling area.

Consider adding a `before_action` to validate that the requestor wants JSON and handle it there instead of stubbing in lots and lots of `respond_to` calls in your controller actions.

Don't forget about `rescue_from` which can blanket rescue from common problems like invalid request types and so on. This can also reduce how much repetitive code you have to do.